# Django object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, django

we can't get the http response as json. Error we encountered:

```
TypeError at /ui/subfix/3
object of type 'type' has no len()
Request Method:GETRequest
```

Code sample:

```
@api_view(('POST',))
@csrf_exempt
@renderer_classes(JSONRenderer,)
def project_image_alternative_form_submit_ajax(request, object_id):
    project_image = ProjectImage.objects.filter(pk=object_id).first()
    response_json = {
            'message': 'Image ...',
    }
    return Response(response_json, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use serializer here to serialize data before sending a response.
If you want to return json response then you can try this way

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

@api_view(('POST',))
@csrf_exempt
@renderer_classes(JSONRenderer,)
def project_image_alternative_form_submit_ajax(request, object_id):
    project_image = ProjectImage.objects.filter(pk=object_id).first()
    response_json = {
            'message': 'Image ...',
    }
    return JsonResponse(response_json)
```